# Node.js Populate is not working with code

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am facing an issue in Node.js where i am trying to populate schema. i have two schema and one is holing reference of "UserSchema", I am adding my code here please anyone help me with this problem. This code is only working if i remove that ".populate('user.email')" part

```
Student.find({'Name': req.studentInfo.Name})
.populate('user.email').exec(function(err, numberOfPendingRequests){
  if(err){
    return next(err);
  }else{
    console.log('\n\n\nFound unapproved requests\n\n\n');
    console.log(numberOfPendingRequests);
    req.studentInfo.unapprovedRequests = numberOfPendingRequests;
    return next();
  }
})

// user.js
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    profile_id   : String,
    token        : String,
    email        : String,
    name         : String,
    provider     : String,
    detailSubmited: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// student.js

var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({

collegeName   : String,
courseName    : String,
courseYear    : String,
user          : {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : User
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
```

Comment: Are you sure assign the user `_id` to student when create that?
Can you show me your create method?

Comment: var newStudent = new Student();
              newStudent.collegeName = req.body.collegeName;
              newStudent.courseName = req.body.courseName;
              newStudent.courseYear = req.body.courseYear;
              newStudent.user = req.user._id;

Answer (score 0):

If you want your populated document to return specific fields only, pass the field name as second argument of the populate function. Like this:

```
Student.find({'Name': req.studentInfo.Name}).populate('user', 'email').exec(function(err, numberOfPendingRequests) {...}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: what you are saying is correct but thing is even i am trying to run different code which is provided in mongoose documencation for population in this link "http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html" is not working.

thats also giving some error.
from docs code its able to save data in DB but not able to populate data

Comment: How about the this part, `Student.find({'Name': req.studentInfo.Name})`? Isn't it supposed to be **name**? Are you encountering any specific error, or is the document is not just populated?